# MVC view loads intermittently

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm in total newb test and learn mode on MVC.

I built a `TestController` and a `Test1` view, and changed RouteConfig to default = Test, Index.  That works, however...

If I break on the `TestController Index ActionResult` line:

```
return View("~/Views/Test/Test1.cshtml");
```

and then continue, it displays my `Test1` view page (which is a new, plain view, no layout, that says "Yow!" inside a div)

If I then remove the break, modify the `Test1` view page (like add one character to "Yow!") and then rerun without the break, I get a `404` error.

If I reset the break and rerun, hit the break and continue, it shows the updated `Test1` view.

That happens consistently.

Why would making a small modification to the `Test1` view cause the localhost to not find the view?  And why would doing a break and continue cause it to find the view?

Comment: I really dont understand what you say, but check the directory when your app starts, it starts where you are at visual studio. maybe is that

Comment: What do you mean by "rerun"? You are refreshing the page? Or hitting Start from VS again?

Comment: Re-run = stop debug and restart debug.  Page refresh does not change the 404.

Comment: New data: it DOES have something to do which document is selected.   If I start debug with the view selected, after the view change, it gives 404 error.  If I start debug with the controller selected after the view change, it works fine.  So the "break/continue" was not relevant, that just happened to coincide with selecting the controller document.  So, maybe this is just a "behavior" of VS?  But what would that be about?  I mean, at least I can go forward now, but it doesn't make sense to have it not work just because the view is selected in VS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go to the properties of your ASP MVC project (right click project, select properties) on the `Web` tab there is an `Start Action` section. By default, **Current Page** is selected, which means that if you start debugging with that view currently opened, VS will try to navigate to the path of that view.

Let me explain that a bit:

- Let's say you create a new MVC project with a Home controller and an
  Index view, and the typical /controller/action/id route. If you have
  "Current Page" selected as the option for "Start Action", and start
  debugging with the Index view opened, VS will try to open a URL like
  `http://localhost:59774/Views/Home/Index.cshtml`
- But as you know, that URL won't work as you need to conform to the
  routes defined in your MVC project. For example
  `http://localhost:59774/Home/Index` or `http://localhost:59774/` would be valid Urls for the index action in the home controller
- That's why when you start or restart debugging with a view opened you
  get a 404. However when you have a controller opened, there is no Current Page and VS will try to navigate to the root of the application (like `http://localhost:59774/`)

You just need to change the `Start Action` option of your project, select **Specific Page** instead and leave it blank. That will result in the root  being opened, same as when you start debugging from a controller.

Also, bear in mind that you can do those kind of changes to the views without the need to recompile or restart debugging.

Comment: That's a great explanation.  I got it to work just as indicated.  And it provided good insight into some of how VS works with MVC.  Many thanks!

Comment: @wayfarer, I am glad that was of help. Remember that you can accept the answer if it was of help to you :)